# I want moving test-output folder from project to other directory where should I put that moving folder code in set up or tear down?

Tags: java, selenium

I want to move test-output folder from project to other directory that I don't need  every time in selenium where should I put that moving folder code in set up or tear down?

Answer (score 1):

You can have this attached to Suite base file

```
public void reportLog(String srcFileName, String reportName, String extension){

    File srcFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\excelfiles\\"+srcFileName+"."+extension);

    String destDir = "reportlog";
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy__hh_mm_ssaa");
    String destFile = reportName+" - "+dateFormat.format(new Date()) + "."+extension;
    try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, new File(destDir + "/" + destFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of ways to do that :

```
new File("/source/directory").renameTo(new File("/target/directory"));
```

And there is `File.move()` method which you can check [oracle document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) too.

Fo Maven, report output directory(or similar fields) in pom.xml file change it as following :

```
<outputDirectory>${user.home}/directory/target</outputDirectory>
```

Comment: @Secluk Ayhan Thanks but where can I put that code in my selenium project? set up method or tear down?.....

Comment: It depending on your framework design, I can't say that and also you can always set your target folder from pom.xml if you are using maven. And I think that output will be generated after tear down method anyway @sap